# What solution can I use to redistribute a RTSP stream?

Tags: streaming

I would like to know if any solution could help with a problem I'm currently facing.

I have access to multiple instances of IP cameras that I would like to get the stream from and redistribute it.

One IP camera can only have 5 direct connections to it at the same time. (Only 5 vlc player can connect directly to the RTSP stream provided by one IP camera.)

I would like to increase this number to an unlimited amount by connecting one 
server directly to an IP camera and then get this one server to redistribute the RTSP stream to the VLC media players asking for this redistributed stream.

I would also like to have minimum delay between what the IP camera sees and what the VLC media player is seeing (Under 2 seconds).

Here's a sketch of what I want to do for clarity purpose:

**Current situation:**

IP Camera->RTSP Stream->VLC Media Player

_____________________->VLC Media Player

_____________________->VLC Media Player

_____________________->VLC Media Player

_____________________->VLC Media Player

_____________________->VLC Media Player(Fail)

_____________________->VLC Media Player(Fail)

...

(Connection failure when more than 5 connections/Can't have more than 5 connections)

**What I want:**

IP Camera->RTSP Stream->Server->RTSP Stream->VLC Media Player

_________________________________________->VLC Media Player

_________________________________________->VLC Media Player

_________________________________________->VLC Media Player

_________________________________________->VLC Media Player

_________________________________________->VLC Media Player

...

(Can have as many player as I want connected to the server that is connected only once to the IP camera. Maximum of 5 servers connected to the same IP camera)

*P.S. I don't have enought reputation to create a **RTSP** or **livestream** tag for this question.*

Comment: I found that maybe webrtc could help... still looking for recommendations

Comment: Here is not an answer but I wonder how did you use Janus WebRTC to complete the stream video problem. My situation is just like you. I can not comment on you post because I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found multiple solutions both free and paid.

Free:

- GStreamer (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/).
- Meetecho's Janus WebRTC Server (https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) with the rtsp plugin configuration.

Paid:

- Flashphoner's Web Call Server 5 (https://flashphoner.com/web-call-server-5/)
- Wowza (https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/50256/can-wowza-redistribute-a-rtsp-stream.html)

I decided to go with Meetecho's Janus solution because at first glance, it can do what I want, redistribute rtsp ip camera feed, but also much more! (Direct chat, webcam redistributing, desktop sharing, ...)